# Android Material Design Animations on pre Lollopop

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

I started building apps using material design but having trouble with animating view transitions on pre lollipop devices.Is there an official way of adding material design animations to your applications using the support library with at least little dependencies on libraries if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Activity/Fragment transitions are Lollipop dependent. Your best bet is to use library like this : [albinmathew/PreLollipopTransition](https://github.com/albinmathew/PreLollipopTransition), although not using it myself I cannot tell how effective it is.